# I am using firebase with Android. I am trying to use facebook login with it. But I am getting firebase error invalid credentials

Tags: facebook-login, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I have tried firebaseUI library but still I get the same error. I cant understand why I keep getting this error.

Answer (score 1):

My facebook application was not public.